# How does the mixing of two gases increase entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I have learnt that $\mathrm{d}S = \mathrm{d}Q_\mathrm{rev}/T$, where $Q$ is the heat energy absorbed by the system. Now consider an insulated compartment with two chambers, separated by a valve. Each chamber consists of a gas at a particular temperature and volume. Now, the valve is screwed open. We know that the entropy of the isolated system will increase as the gases have more freedom.

But, starting with the assumption that the walls were insulated, where did the heat energy come from?

How did the entropy increase?

Comment: I am sure this is NOT a duplicate, as no one asked this specific question, perhaps because it is stupid.

Comment: isn't the equation you mentioned deals with  "entropy of the surrounding" ?

Comment: No, I believe this equation holds good for any system.

Comment: :) looking forward for a clear answer +1

Comment: The $Q_{rev}$ is reversible heat. Such mixing is not a reversible process. There is no way to unmix the gases. // You can heat water convert to it to steam, cool the steam to water and keep cycling as long as you want. That is a reversible process.

Comment: Sure, but we can still calculate the entropy somehow, right?

Comment: In fact, the formula is  -nR*summation(xlnx), where x is the mole fraction of the ith gas.

Comment: The entropy of mixing can be derived by considering the chemical potential of an ideal gas then finding $\Delta G$ and hence $\Delta S$, or equivalently by considering the number of different microstates in the unmixed and mixed states then using Boltzmann's formula $S = k_\mathrm{B} \ln W$.

Comment: Yes, but since entropy of the system increases, the gases should have absorbed some heat.From where?

Comment: @orthocresol Just if anyone is interested. I had written up a derivation of the entropy of mixing formula via the $\Delta G$-route in [this answer of mine](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/6952/189).

Comment: The process is not reversible, which means that $\mathrm{d}S \gt \mathrm{d}q/T = 0$. The equality only holds in the reversible case, which is why you have a subscript rev. So the whole premise of your question is wrong. The entropy change of an irreversible adiabatic process is always greater than zero.

Comment: I thought that for an irreversible process, we calculate entropy change by assuming a reversible process from the initial to the final state.Still, I don't quite understand how entropy increases from the chemistry perspective, for this situation.

Comment: Can you tell me a way of "reversibly" mixing two gases for which you can work out that $\mathrm{d}q = 0$? Because I can't think of any. As for the second part, entropy is not something that is supposed to be interpreted pictorially. It is not a function that we can observe or control. It is merely defined to be a state function with the property $\mathrm{d}S = \mathrm{d}q_{\mathrm{rev}}/T$. The best we can do is "entropy is a measure of disorder", and obviously a mixed system has greater disorder than one where the two gases are separated.

Comment: Agreed, but how can a system become more disordered without any absorption of energy?

Comment: Why does it have to absorb energy? The Second Law tells you that an isolated system (which by definition cannot absorb any energy from its surroundings) always tends to maximum entropy.

Comment: I think I get your point. The only issue is that my book has derived the formula for entropy change, considering it to be a reversible process.It has just used algebraic manipulation and other thermodynamic formulas, without mentioning where the heat came from, or commenting upon the reversibility of the process

Comment: @orthocresol I am not sure if my argument is total bs or not since my thermodynamics classes lie in a distant past, but might the following be a possible explanation: When the two gases expand to fill the larger (common) volume created by opening the compartements, they release expansion work, $-p dV$. This released expansion work is not absorbed by any surroundings but converted into heat energy, $dQ_{\mathrm{rev}}$, since the entropy of the system increases because of the expansion by $dS = \frac{dQ_{\mathrm{rev}}}{T}$.

Comment: @Philipp I think you are right. There is a theoretically reversible way to carry out this reaction, described in Levine's *Physical Chemistry* 6th ed., which involves separate isothermal expansion as you mentioned ($w < 0$, so $q_\mathrm{rev} > 0$ since the process is isothermal and $\Delta U = 0$) followed by a hypothetical isothermal mixing of the expanded gases using semipermeable membranes (for which $q_\mathrm{rev} = w = 0$). I've attached a pdf of the relevant pages [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0GATVY1ly6cbFZfcjRkS2cxUUE/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: I didn't quite understand still.Can you explain a little better please?

Comment: I understood the part where we devised a way to carry the process out reversibly.Since this is the case, where DID the heat come from?

Comment: @Kaylan The process is simply a matter of energy conversion: Some kind of "volume energy" is converted into heat energy (which is linked to entropy) during the process of mixing. So, the heat comes from the gas expansion, i.e. from within the system itself.

Comment: @orthocresol Thx, that restores my faith in my lingering thermodynamics knowledge :)

Comment: Yeah, ortho Cresol has answered most of the questions that I ask on this website. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a reversible process to do what you are asking for (i.e., unmixing the gases reversibly).  You have a cylinder containing the two gases already mixed.  The cylinder has a piston.  Connected to this main cylinder are two other cylinders joined to it through semipermeable membranes.  Each membrane allows one of the gases to pass, but not the other.  You gradually advance the piston in the main cylinder while, at the same time moving the other pistons outward in the other two cylinders so that, at any time, the pressures of the pure gases in the attached cylinders are equal to their partial pressures in the main cylinder.  The change in entropy for this adiabatic reversible process is zero.  This is the first step.  Now, in the second step, we close off the semipermeable membranes, and compress each of the pure gases in the two cylinders isothermally and reversibly to the original total pressure that was present in the main chamber.  So, if $p_1$ was the partial pressure of one of the gases in the main chamber and $p_2$ was the partial pressure of the other gas in the main chamber, the total pressure of the pure gases in their chambers after completing step 2 will be $p_1+p_2$.  The change in entropy for the 2-step process we described is minus the entropy of mixing.  So, if the process is done in reverse, the entropy of mixing will be positive.